# How to initialize template static member in derived C++ class with different namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, macros, namespaces, static-members

I have the following base class:

```
 namespace n1 {

    template <class T, typename A>
    class FSM
    {
      protected:
        typedef void (T::*pfun)();
        typedef std::map<A, pfun > transition_table_t;
        static transition_table_t _transition_table; 
    };

    } // namespace n1
```

and the following set of macros to define the static members in the derived class field

```
#define BEGIN_TRANSITION_MAP(class_type, state_type) \
template <>  std::map< state_type, class_type::*pfun >  FSM<class_type, state_type>::_transition_table= {

#define TRANSITION_ENTRY(state, action) \
{state, action},

#define END_TRANSITION_MAP \
};
```

Now, in another `cpp` file, I defined the next derived class:

```
namespace n1{
    namespace n2{
    namespace n3{

    enum state{
        state1,
        state2,
    };

    class derive : public FSM<derive, state>
    {
        friend class FSM<derive, state>;
        void event_a();
        void event_b();
    };

    BEGIN_TRANSITION_MAP(n2::n3::derive, n2::n3::state) 
    TRANSITION_ENTRY(n2::n3::state1, &n2::n3::derive::event_a)
    TRANSITION_ENTRY(n2::n3::state2, &n2::n3::derive::event_b)
    END_TRANSITION_MAP

    }//namespace n3
    }//namespace n2
}//namespace n1
```

This code compiled ok under `g++ 4.7` with `c++11`.

I would like to write the same but without doing the base class `friend` in the derived class and without the need to specify all the namespaces in macros. Something like:

```
namespace n1{
    namespace n2{
    namespace n3{

    enum state{
        state1,
        state2,
    };

    class derive : public FSM<derive, state>
    {
        void event_a();
        void event_b();   
    };

    BEGIN_TRANSITION_MAP(derive, state) 
    TRANSITION_ENTRY(state1, &derive::event_a)
    TRANSITION_ENTRY(state2,&derive::event_a)
    END_TRANSITION_MAP

    } //namespace n3
    } //namespace n2
} //namespace n1
```

It this possible, or is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: that code: `typedef std::map transition_table_t;` compiles ok?

Comment: sorry, its  my first post and i dont know why all <> has been deleted. you can see also the template definiton its wrong also.

Comment: I don't see why do you need to declare the derived class as friend.

Comment: sorry, i simplified too the problem :)

Comment: new example edited to show the necesity of friend class. it is clear now?

Comment: It is clear now. What about declare `event_a` and `event_b` members as public? Is that a desired solution or you prefer they be private for the rest of the world?

Comment: they must be private because these members should only be acceded by the class.

Answer (score 0):

Define the transition table only in the derived class. Then you refer to it from the base class using derived::transition_table. This is called the curiously recurring template pattern (google it).

```
template <typename derived>
class FSM
{
public:
  typedef std::map<state_type, event_type> transition_table_t;
  // do not define transition_table here

  void function()
  {
    // use transition table of derived type
    derived::transition_table.do_something();
  }
};

class Derived : public FSM<Derived>
{
public:
  static transition_table_t transition_table;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the point is to have the template inside a library, and the final user only have to define the derive class, so i wouldn't like to let the final user to define the transition_table. furthermore, I would like only initialized transition table once per template instantiation, this is why it is static member, and I never change during the execution

Comment: You'd have to make it static anyway, I updated the code above. You might want to have a look at [boost::msm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html) which implements a state machine as static construct at compile time. I've also derived a simplified version from it which you can find on my website if you're interested.